# Performance implication of a view with simple calculations over pre-calculated data

Tags: sql-server, database, view

My application consumes data from different sources which should be stored in a DB for reporting purposes. The fields are the same and the data is oly about a half-dozen fields but the data is sometimes reported in different units.

e.g. To get speed in m/s

- from TypeA, speed = (reported value - 1024) * 0.1
- from typeB, speed = (reported value) * 0.001

I a considering whether to hard-code this conversion in the application logic and write the calculated values into the DB, or to write the raw values received into the DB and use views to do a union of TypeA records with TypeB records, adding simple calculations this way, or to rely on it being built into reporting queries to do the same thing.

The core DB table might grow by as much as a million rows per day, though the data is simple, so my initial thought was to keep the DB as simple as possible, more along a data warehouse principle.

But as a coder rather than a DBA I have no real idea if this is so trivial a good DB will not have any problems.

Comment: Strict microservice theory would probably say that you should do the computation in the database, and send the computed value to your application layer (using either a query or a view).  That being said, if you feel that the extra overhead would overload your database, and you can't scale up, then sending the raw data to your application and doing the math there is another option.

Comment: My application is writing the data to DB, not reading it - I've clarified my query but I think your comment still stands either way? I don't control the external data sources.

Comment: So you are asking whether you should write raw data or aggregates of raw data then?

Comment: Indeed. Is doing mass conversion in a DB query every time likely to realistically impact anything, or in the context of generating reports is this trivial? There is a slight inconvenience when inspecting the raw DB data too, I suppose.

Comment: "... sometimes reported in different units." is a concerning phrase. It would IMO be far better to record the information correctly during insertion. You could use a view (materialized or not) or a computed column or in the queries that need this information. But also sounds like premature optimization. The calculation must be done somewhere. Much depends on how this information is used and the frequency. To know the impact, you must measure using a realistic simulation.

Comment: And consider the possibility that your data provider changes. IMO (again) your app should do the conversion since it has the specific knowledge of the units. You generally should not store kilograms and pounds (example) in a column and depend on a flag of some sort to know how what the unit is.

Comment: @SMor Protocols don't normally change or any consumer is now broken... there would be some version Id which would either be used in code logic, or DB logic. But your point stands that this is conceptually 'internal' data to that protocol, not relevant to the end user. It could even be proprietary (secret) and shouldn't be exposed.